# Make Gnome screen lock after 1 hour, not 15 minutes?

Tags: fedora, gnome, screensaver

I am using Fedora 20 with Gnome. The screen Power Savings blanks the screen after 15 minutes and then the screen gets automatically locked. I'd like to have the screen blanked and locked after an hour, but the pop-up only goes up to 15 minutes. Is there any way to make it an hour?

Comment: I'm actually quite baffled by how the designers thought when they designed that box. I'm fairly sure that there are a lot of users who want more than 15 minutes.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can put the desired values directly in GSettings, either via the *dconf-editor* app (i.e. "GNOME regedit") or command line:

- Timeout for blanking the screen (seconds; 0 = never):

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 3600
  ```
- Timeout for locking the screen after blanking (seconds; 0 = instant):

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay 0
  ```

Comment: That is great. Is there anyplace where all of this is documented?

Comment: Probably not. But the schemas and keys themselves do have descriptions, visible in `dconf-editor`.

Comment: And you can also get the current settings via: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay`

Comment: Just for the sake of completion, there is also `org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled` for just enabling/disabling the locking. If you set this to `false`, the `lock-delay` will be ignored.

Comment: If you run the above commands from an SSH session and gets a warning about spawning dbus you need to either launch dbus or use terminal in the local session.

Answer (score 8):

This can also be accessed by using:

- Settings -> Privacy

  [image: screenshot]

Comment: I only see the `lock-delay` option, worded as "Lock screen after blank for", and not the `idle-delay` option, which is what most people probably want to control.

Comment: This suggestion indeed presents the pull-down for idle duration before lock screen starts. However, the OP wanted to know how to set it for 1 hour; the pull-down stops at 15 minutes.

Comment: In Ubuntu 17.10 (which uses the GNOME Shell interface), it goes up to 1 hour...